# How do I open DrawerNavigator upon clicking TabNavigator item in react-nevigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

[image]

I'm using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) and trying to open the drawer (with DrawerNavigator) upon clicking tab item in the TabNavigator. My current code looks like this:

```
class OpenDrawerScreen extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen"); // Opening Drawer
    }

    render() {        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>Dummy view - Nothing to see here.</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    TabItem1: {
        screen: TabOneScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"Tab 1"
        }
    },
    TabItem2: {
        screen: OpenDrawerScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"Open Drawer"
        }
    }    
}, {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom'
});

const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    DrawerItem1: {
        screen: TabNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawer: {
                label: 'Drawer 1'
            },
        },
    },
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerNav />
    );
  }
}
```

But that's not working and the result is, the drawer is opened every time the app starts, instead of only when clicking on the 'OPEN DRAWER' tab item. Is there other life-cycle method I should open the drawer from instead of opening from the componentWillMount() method, or is there another way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean  that for the first time of page load it always open the drawer, but want to open it at the time when you click on yo tab navigator right ?

Comment: @ashutosh-pandey Yes. The expected result is to open the drawer every time 'OPEN DRAWER' tab is clicked. The only way I could think of is to programmatically open the drawer while the page is rendering. But the result right now is when the app is opened, the drawer is already opened on the first screen without clicking any tab items and it won't open again anymore when the tab item is clicked.

Comment: ok i got the problem .

Comment: Any luck with this?